# Show an OpenCV image with PyQt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm learning to use `pyqt5` and `qt designer` and I am so confused.

My goal is show a picture when I click a push button because in a future I want to combine all of this with `opencv`.

Now I have a window with a push button and an image (it is a label).

Code of the conversion from `.ui` to `.py`:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        # Omitted code
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.imagen)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PROG PRUEBAS QT"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Escala de grises"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/chchch/img.png\"/></p></body></html>"))

    #
    def imagen(self):
        img = cv.imread('img.png', 0)
        cv.imshow('sss', img)
        cv.imwrite('pichi.png', img)
    #

import noe_rc
```

But now, when I run it with my Pycharm, it crashes in the `import noe_rc`. And if I commented, the image doesn't appear.

**PS:** If I comment the import the `imagen` function works well but the image appears in a new windows.

Comment: What "crashes", PyCharm or the program? Is there any error message? Is `noe_rc` the file generated by pyrcc5?

Answer (score 12):

To display an OpenCV image, you have to convert the image into a `QImage` then into a `QPixmap` where you can display the image with a `QLabel`

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import cv2
import sys

class DisplayImageWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisplayImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show picture')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_image)
        self.image_frame = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image_frame)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_image(self):
        self.image = cv2.imread('placeholder4.PNG')
        self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.image.data, self.image.shape[1], self.image.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        self.image_frame.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    display_image_widget = DisplayImageWidget()
    display_image_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using this example image,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had issues with the output, it was just lines - blank and white. So, I removed `rgbSwapped()` and changed `Format_RGB888` with `Format_ARGB32`. Thank you for this answer. This answer was a lifesaver. Thanks a million.

Comment: I meant, this format `Format_RGBA8888_Premultiplied`

Comment: My image has the right colors but was slanted I added `self.image.strides[0]` just before `QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888` according to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52869969/14476967) answer.

Comment: Why not using Format_BGR888 without rgbSwapped()